# Files Connect with Community Users: Possible?

Tags: community, files-connect

I would like to use Files Connect for Community Users. I cannot find documentation excluding Community Users from this functionality, and yet I suspect it is not feasible based on trial and error.

I have granted access via Permission Set:

- Files Connect Cloud.
- External Data Source Access.

This is the appropriate access level for this functionality.

But, when attempting to navigate to the Connected Sources link in the Community my Community Users simply see a modal with a permissions error message.

> "You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help
>   or to request access.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue with your community users not seeing the files?

Comment: no luck. I am not sure this is a supported feature. please advise if you know otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is supported since Winter '16. Check out the Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334995&type=1&mode=1) on this. Have a look at the set-up guide [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_connect_perm.htm&type=5), it has a walkthrough on assigning permission sets for users to be able to access cloud-based data sources.